# Is it possible to draw a path Line with a transparent fill or no fill at all?

Tags: path, javafx, fill

I am new to JavaFX and am trying to create a chart using Path. I am wondering if it is possible to draw a path Line with a transparent fill or no fill at all? I have attempted to draw a line with no fill by playing around with setFill() and setFillRule() and have still not solved my problem. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide your [code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe an image of what output you are getting and what output you wish.

Comment: First add a `MoveTo` element (to initial coordinate) then add `LineTo` elements to the `Path`. The default values for `fill=null` and `fillRule=NON_ZERO` are appropriate to your use case so you may not to set them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<SVGPath content="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10" fill="TRANSPARENT" layoutY="540.0" stroke="#b29d9d" strokeWidth="25.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" />
```

or

```
setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```